# Powershell Array conversion

Tags: powershell

I am using the .net web object to retrieve a text file which is comma delimited.

The variable comes back as a single array as if I had used `Get-Content` to load it from disk. I use a `foreach` loop to insert a comma between the date and the time values in the array so I have 3 columns.

I then save the array to disk using `Set-Content` and then reload it using `Import-CSV` to get a Multi Dimensional array that I can then use with `select`.

Is there a way of converting the array type without saving it to disk and reloading it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your code and some sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the text into `ConvertFrom-Csv`. It works on both an array of strings(like `Get-Content` returns), and on multiline strings.

Array of strings:

```
$res = @"
Name,Age
Frode,22
Jesus,2014
"@ -split "`r`n"

$res | ConvertFrom-Csv

Name  Age 
----  --- 
Frode 22  
Jesus 2014
```

One big multiline string:

```
$res = @"
Name,Age
Frode,22
Jesus,2014
"@

$res | ConvertFrom-Csv

Name  Age 
----  --- 
Frode 22  
Jesus 2014
```

Comment: You're welcome :)  If you consider this to be the correct answer for your question, please mark it as so by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.